# Unable to access Neo4j webadmin on Azure VM

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008, neo4j

I have installed neo4j 1.9.2 on a virtual machine on Azure. The VM OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter version.

I have created an TCP end point (on Azure Management Portal) for port 7474 and created an inbound firewall rule that will allow connection to port 7474.

When I put the VM's DNS name and the port number followed by webadmin nothing happens

```
https://myVMDNS:7474/webadmin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I un-commented `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0` and it works fine!!

Comment: did this, restarted the service - still no effect :(

Comment: Mike, I apologize - it's now ok. was my bad knowledge of networking

Comment: dont worry, we all have all been there.